# "Illegal Target for Annotation" Error Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write this item as a weapon I can use in battles along with armor for a text based rpg.

```
"bronze_sword": {
  "name": "Bronze Sword",
  "type": "weapon",
  "atk": "3",
  "examine": "A shiny bronze sword.",
},

"turian_garb": {
  "name": "Turian Garb",
  "type": "Armour",
  "def": "1",
  "examine": "Your combat uniform.", 
}


######################

inventory = [""]
tutorial_chest1 = ["bronze_sword", "turian_garb"]
```

"Invalid Syntax" Errors appear when adding a comma (pointing to the comma), and when removed the name of the dictionary shows "Illegal target for annotation". Please consider that I am new to code in general, and this is my first proper project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decalre a variable `dicts` and initialize a dictionary first with curly braces.

```
dicts={"bronze_sword": {
  "name": "Bronze Sword",
  "type": "weapon",
  "atk": "3",
  "examine": "A shiny bronze sword.",
},

"turian_garb": {
  "name": "Turian Garb",
  "type": "Armour",
  "def": "1",
  "examine": "Your combat uniform.", 
}}
```

OR without initialize a variable make dictionary with curly braces like this

```
{"bronze_sword": {
  "name": "Bronze Sword",
  "type": "weapon",
  "atk": "3",
  "examine": "A shiny bronze sword.",
},

"turian_garb": {
  "name": "Turian Garb",
  "type": "Armour",
  "def": "1",
  "examine": "Your combat uniform.", 
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very grateful for experienced people helping me out (: